# Index defrag in a secondary AG

Tags: sql, sql-server, high-availability

Is it necessary to defrag indexes in a database participating in a secondary availability group?

I am hoping to determine weather of not I need to create jobs on my secondary to defrag indexes or will the job on the primary take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, the database on the AG secondary is a page-for-page copy of the primary database. Any operation (including index rebuilds and reorgs) are reflected on the secondary.

That said, I'd wonder what problem you're trying to solve by scheduling index maintenance. I'd suggest reading [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/) and see if you're doing what you think you are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the article I'll read what Brent has to say on the subject.